# nginx failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: nginx, http

2013/01/12 15:47:06 [error] 1755#0: *876440 open() "/home/bitrix/www/catalog/gps/naviga/explayy/explay955" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 38.100.21.62, server: bx, request: "GET /catalog/gps/naviga/explayy/explay955 HTTP/1.1",...

2013/01/12 15:47:07 [error] 1755#0: *876440 open() "/home/bitrix/www/catalog/photo/cameras/canon/canon-powershot-a810-black" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 38.100.21.62, server: bx, request: "GET /catalog/photo/cameras/canon/canon-powershot-a810-black HTTP/1.1", ....

/etc/nginx/bx/site_enabled/s1.conf

```
server {        include     bx/node_port.conf;        include     bx/node_host.conf;        server_name_in_redirect off;        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;        proxy_set_header Host $host:80;        set $proxyserver "http://127.0.0.1:8888";        index index.php;        root /home/bitrix/www;        if (-f /home/bitrix/www/.htsecure) {            rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$host$1 permanent;        }        include bx/conf/bitrix.conf;    }
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user bitrix;worker_processes 8;error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;pid /var/run/nginx.pid;worker_rlimit_nofile 10240;events {    use epoll;    worker_connections  10240;}http {    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;    default_type application/octet-stream;    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $status                                '            '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '            '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';    log_format common '$remote_addr - - [$time_local] "$request" $status $bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $msec';    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log  common;    access_log          off;    sendfile            on;    tcp_nopush          on;    tcp_nodelay         on;    client_max_body_size        1024m;    client_body_buffer_size     4m;    proxy_connect_timeout       300;    proxy_send_timeout      300;    proxy_read_timeout      300;    proxy_buffer_size       64k;    proxy_buffers           8 256k;    proxy_busy_buffers_size     256k;    proxy_temp_file_write_size  10m;        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;    error_page 404 = /404.php;    gzip            on;    gzip_proxied        any;    gzip_static     on;    gzip_http_version   1.0;    gzip_types      application/x-javascript text/css;    include conf.d/*.conf;    include bx/site_enabled/*.conf;    include bx/site_ext_enabled/*.conf;}
```

/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirectfastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

nginx -V

```
nginx-catap: nginx-catap version: 1.1.0nginx-catap: built by gcc 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13) (GCC)nginx-catap: TLS SNI support enablednginx-catap: configure arguments: --builddir=/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/nginx-catap-1.1.0/objs --add-module=../modules/ngx_http_response_module --add-module=../modules/ngx_http_is_bot --add-module=../modules/ngx_http_rnd_filter_module --add-module=../modules/ngx_http_hash --add-module=../modules/ngx_http_limit_var_module --add-module=../modules/ngx_http_dump_config_module --add-module=../modules/ngx_http_auth_request_module --add-module=../modules/ngx_http_bytes_filter_module --add-module=../modules/ngx_http_compose_filter_module --add-module=../modules/ngx_http_gunzip_filter_module --add-module=../modules/ngx_http_ip_tos_filter_module --add-module=../modules/ngx_http_upstream_keepalive --add-module=../modules/nginx-upload-module --add-module=../modules/nginx-eval-module --add-module=../modules/nginx-mogilefs-module --add-module=../modules/nginx-syslog-module --add-module=../modules/nginx-udplog-module --add-module=../modules/nginx-upload-progress-module --add-module=../modules/ngx_http_delay_module --user=nginx --group=nginx --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/subsys/nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -march=i386 -mtune=i686'
```

Как бы ссылка норм открывается... ЧПУ (//photo/cameras/canon/canon-powershot-a810-black).. но в логах он пишет как ошибка...

как исправить?

Comment: или это нормально?

Comment: Посмотрите, что происходит Firebug'ом или DragonFly'ем: я подозреваю, что может там происходит редирект. 1. не находится URL, обработка передаётся 404.php, который, найдя нужную страницу, перекидывает на 2. на правильный URL, который открывается без ошибок.Либо вообще все страницы в итоге выдаются скриптом 404.php ? =)